Spyder error while launching it from Conda
I am getting an error message "Not possible for Spyder to create console for you". I am launching spyder from conda, It opens up spyder correctly however, it gives an error message. I did check and I have correctly installed spyder-kernels. I am not able to understand the issue here. I am using Spyder 4.1.4 and python 3.8.3 64 bit and spyder-kernels 2.4.4.
Can someone help me with this issue ?

what error did you get exactly? I think you should be more precise
